# Array of maps in PineScript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

Is it possible to define list of maps in Pinescript and use it as a function of a library?

I want to do something like this in the library code:

```
// @function Converts map of strings to a flat JSON string.
// @param data The map of key value pairs.
// @returns JSON string for simple map.
export dict_to_json(simple map<string, string> data) =>
    simple string [] arr = array.new_string()
    for [key, val] in data
        array.push(arr, "\"" + key + "\":\"" + val + "\"")
    "{" + array.join(arr, ",") + "}"

// @function Converts array of maps to an JSON array string.
// @param data The array of map of key value pair strings.
// @returns JSON array string for array of simple maps.
export array_of_maps_to_json(??? array<map<string, string>> data) =>
    simple string [] arr = array.new_string()
    for [i, data_point] in data
        array.push(arr, dict_to_json(data_point))
    "[" + array.join(arr, ",") + "]"
```

For this I can't figure out how the signature of the `array_of_maps_to_json(...)` function should look like.
Does anyone have any idea?

---

Meanwhile I've found a disgusting solution.
I really hope that's not the only workaround.

```
dict_to_json(simple map<string, string> data) =>
    simple string [] arr = array.new_string()
    for [key, val] in data
        array.push(arr, "\"" + key + "\":\"" + val + "\"")
    "{" + array.join(arr, ",") + "}"

type mydict
    map<string, string> dict

array_of_maps_to_json(mydict[] data) =>
    simple string [] arr = array.new_string()
    for [i, data_point] in data
        array.push(arr, dict_to_json(data_point.dict))
    "[" + array.join(arr, ",") + "]"

simple mydict [] arr = array.new<mydict>()
array.push(arr, mydict.new(data1))
array.push(arr, mydict.new(data2))
json_data := array_of_maps_to_json(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create array of maps by using types.
Create type that has map as its field.
Then you can create array of types and iterate trough them

```
export type myMap
    map<string, string> jsonmap = na

export array_of_maps_to_json(myMap[] data) =>
   ...
```

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I did (you can see it in the question referred as "disgusting solution").

Comment: There is no array of maps or array of arrays in pine, so it is the only option